# Why this easy jquery code won't change the font-size

Tags: jquery

Here's my jquery code. If you can't see any flaw in it, please proceed to see JSfiddle here at http://jsfiddle.net/J4ZgB/3/ Thanks.

```
$(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        var s=$('#p_content').css("font-size");
        s+=4;
        $('#p_content').css("font-size",s+"px");
    })
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had two errors.. fixed code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        var s = parseInt($('#p_content').css("font-size"), 10);
        s += 4;
        $('#p_content').css("font-size",s+"px");
    })
})
```

1. You need to parse the numeric value of the font size, which contain "px" - luckily, `parseInt` takes the first digits in a string and converts them to number ignoring the rest of the string.
2. You tried to set font of element with ID `p_cont` (in jsFiddle) while the real ID is `p_content`.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J4ZgB/5/).

Answer (score 2):

Because the value of `s` is `"14px"` so `"14px" + 4 + "px"` is `"14px4px"` which is not valid CSS.  You have to parse the number out of "14px" before treating it like a number.

You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/J4ZgB/2/.  Just click on your link and see what the alert shows.

You can use this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        var item = $('#p_content');
        var s = parseInt(item.css("font-size"), 10);
        s += 4;
        item.css("font-size", s + "px");
    })
})
```

Which you can see working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/J4ZgB/8/.

FYI, I also saved the jQuery object into a local variable rather than running the selector query twice in the same block of code.

Comment: You can simply use `parseInt(.., 10)` instead of a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Cus you didn't write your #p_cont as #p_content

```
$('#p_cont').css("font-size",s);
```

Should be

```
$('#p_content').css("font-size",s);
```

And I have added `parseInt`

```
var s=parseInt($('#p_content').css("font-size"));
```

DEmo: http://jsfiddle.net/J4ZgB/9/

Total result:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="a">click to make font bigger</span>
<div id="p_content">
Echo apis are created to simulate Ajax calls: /echo/json/ for JSON, http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/ for JSONP, /echo/html/ for HTML and /echo/xml/ for XML. ...
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#a").click(function(){
        var s=parseInt($('#p_content').css("font-size"));
        s+=4;
        $('#p_content').css("font-size",s);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#a').click(function(){
        var s = parseInt($('#p_content').css("fontSize"), 10);
        s += 4;
        $('#p_content').css('fontSize', s+'px');
    })
})
```

Comment: c'mon ... copy-paste of @ShadowWizard :)

Comment: Haha no, the answer wasn't there when i started writing mine.

Comment: that was why i've added the smiley ... :)

Answer (score 1):

When you retrieve the current font size you get a string returned:

```
var s = $('#p_content').css("font-size"); //Returns 14px
```

Try to parse the integer value when you get it:

```
var s = parseInt($('#p_content').css("font-size"));
```

Second error is that the paragraph selector string is wrong when you try to get it the second time, where it should say #p_content it says #p_cont.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J4ZgB/11/

General advice is to use the console logging more and check what values you are getting from functions in order to troubleshoot your own scripts.

Comment: +1 for the general advice, the rest already appears in previous answers.